# Using a CASE or IF..ELSE within WHERE clause's AND part - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server. 
The SELECT part for this SP is as follows :

```
SELECT * FROM demoTable dt
INNER JOIN demoTable2 dt2
WHERE
      (@StartDate IS NULL OR dt.StartDate = @StartDate OR (dt.StartDate >= @StartDate and dt.EndDate <= @EndDate))   
      AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR dt.EndDate = @EndDate OR (dt.StartDate >= @StartDate and dt.EndDate <= @EndDate))
```

Now I want to modify the above WHERE clause part after the AND condition.
I have added 3 new parameters/variables which are being passed to this SP.

```
@ID int , @isAdmin int and @Date varchar(50)
```

Using the values of these variables I'm trying to manipulate the above WHERE clause as follows :

```
 WHERE
   @StartDate IS NULL OR dt.StartDate = @StartDate OR (dt.StartDate >= @StartDate and dt.EndDate <= @EndDate))   
    -- Logic change below          
    AND(
    CASE WHEN (@ID != 100 AND @isAdmin != 1)
    THEN (@EndDate IS NULL OR dt.EndDate = @EndDate OR (dt.StartDate >= @StartDate and dt.EndDate <= @EndDate))    
    ELSE (dt.EndDate>sysdatetime()) 
    END)
```

But after this modification I'm receiving an error.

Error statement :

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.
```

This error is pointing to the line where I've used IS NULL from the modified logic part.

Basically what I want to do is to apply the original logic for **AND**  i.e.

```
(@EndDate IS NULL OR dt.EndDate = @EndDate OR (dt.StartDate >= @StartDate and dt.EndDate <= @EndDate))
```

only when the

```
(@ID != 100 AND isAdmin != 1)
```

holds true or else I want to apply the new logic i.e.

```
(dt.EndDate>sysdatetime()
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I dont know why that CASE dont work. Did you try with something simpler and add things until break? start with something like `CASE WHEN @ID != 100 THEN true ELSE false`

Comment: WHERE
      (@StartDate IS NULL

vs 

WHERE
   StartDate IS NULL

I think you are just missing a @

Comment: @KinSlayerUY in that case db will think is refering to `dt.StartDate`

Comment: The line was also missing a left parenthesis: `(@`, so this could have been the only issue.

Comment: @PeterAbolins That is `WHERE  StartDate IS NULL` should be `WHERE
   (@StartDate IS NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a special condition for `@ID !=100 AND isAdmin !=1`

You don't need case/when, you need just a valid boolean expression

change :

```
AND(
    CASE WHEN (@ID != 100 AND isAdmin != 1)
    THEN (@EndDate IS NULL OR dt.EndDate = @EndDate OR (dt.StartDate >= 
@StartDate and dt.EndDate <= @EndDate))    
    ELSE (dt.EndDate>sysdatetime()) 
    END
)
```

to

```
AND(
    ((@ID != 100 AND isAdmin != 1) AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR dt.EndDate = @EndDate OR (dt.StartDate >= @StartDate and dt.EndDate <= @EndDate)))    
    OR
    ((@ID == 100 OR isAdmin == 1)  AND (dt.EndDate>sysdatetime()) )
)
```

Comment: I dont think those two are aquivalent

Comment: @Indent nope this didn't give me the required results.